# save data in android webview DOMStorage before loadurl()

Tags: javascript, android, json, webview

I want to save some data in webview DOM Storage before loading url in webview.

What I did so far... in 
**AndroidActivity.java**

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

CookieSyncManager.createInstance(webView.getContext()); // Deprecated
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
String cookieString = "auth-token="+ LoginService.getCookie()+";
domain=.example.com";
cookieManager.setCookie("http://example.com", cookieString);
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync(); // Deprecated

Map<String, String> cookie = new HashMap<String, String>();
cookie.put("Cookie", "auth-token=" + LoginService.getCookie());

webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomBrowser());
final WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

// set below mentioned data in DOM Storage...

webView.loadUrl(url, cookie);

private class CustomBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I want to put a `JSON` in DOM Storage its key is `"app.identity"`and value as below, before webview load my url:

```
{"username":"shobhit@gmail.com","roles":{"ROLE_Student_Trial":true,"ROLE_student":true,"ROLE_Student_Unlimited":true},"type":"student","lastLogin":1443704579000,"token":"123"}
```

I am new to android, I know the way in javaScript, we can save data in local storage using `localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(value));`

Comment: I haven't tried this but think webView.loadUrl("javascript:localStorage.setItem('key', " + JSON.stringify(value) +")") ought to work

Comment: but it should load my url after storing this json in DOMStorage.

Comment: Like I said, I haven't tried it myself but it should work. ie that line of code can be executed before your real page load. I might be able to experiment during the weekend but for now I think you can try it yourself :)

Comment: It won't work, above script will save data with different name, i.e. in different storage and when I load url it uses its own storage, with different name.

Comment: Did you reach that conclusion after inspecting the databases?

Comment: I made changes in web application my approach was wrong.

Comment: any progress with this problem? Any workaround?

Comment: no,but still I am looking, if anyone can able to insert some persistent data in web view localStorage with same domain name.

Comment: Worked around by changing requirements server-side. I guess it is still not possible. Thanks for reviewing.